# What programming language can I use to implement this into my website?

Tags: html

What programming language can I use to implement the moving text that appears on the users screen like in the [example](https://caferati.me). Could someone recommend me any tutorials which I can also watch to develop my understanding of how to do this and get a basic starting template.

Due to recently starting I'm only aware of how to use html, css & bootstrap.

Comment: ‬ JavaScript‬‬‬‬. ‬

Comment: And jQuery also as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css3 animations` to do this like the one below.

```css
body{
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
} 

p{
  color: lime; 
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}

p:nth-child(2){
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}

p a{
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span{
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2{
  0%{width: 0;}
  50%{width: 0;}
  100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes blink{
  to{opacity: .0;}
}

::selection{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<p>hi folks, this is typing animation using CSS</p>
<p>created with ♥ 
:)<span>|</span></p>
```

Source: https://codepen.io/rusjames/pen/uAFhE